# How to use WeirdX applet instead of X11 for remote connections in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, x11, x11forwarding

1. When I am away, I've got an Apple PowerBook set up to use X11 forwarding with SSH to connect to a remote iMac client in my room for server administration.
2. Whenever I start X client programs on the client iMac, X11 would start on my PowerBook, which is OK, but...
3. Question: Is it possible to change my settings so I can use the [WeirdX](http://www.jcraft.com/weirdx/) (a web-based java X server) applet to take care of the X client programs instead of Mac OS X's default X11? Is there a config file I can edit to chance the $DISPLAY variable, and what should I set it to? Is this even the issue?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default $DISPLAY variable is set by `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.x.startx.plist`.  You can disable the X11 autostart feature by running

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.x.startx.plist
```

but that shouldn't be necessary — just set $DISPLAY by whatever means you feel like using (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`) and ssh away.